# Trouble with Arrays in C

Tags: c, arrays, loops

I'm supposed to create a basic program creating an inventory using arrays but i'm having difficulty getting them to print one by one in a list after entering them in the loop, this is what i'm working with right now. The first loop is designed to finish once the user enters '0' as the barcode. Any help or guidance in the right direction is appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int barcode[100], quantity[100], i;
    double price[100];

    printf("Grocery Store Inventory\n");
    printf("=======================\n");

    for(i=0;i<100;i++){
        printf("Barcode:");
        scanf("%d", &barcode[i]);

        if (barcode[100]==0){
            break;
        }

        printf("Price:");
        scanf("%lf", &price[i]);

        printf("Quantity:");
        scanf("%d", &quantity[i]);
    }

    printf("Goods in Stock\n");
    printf("==============\n\n");

    printf("Barcode    Price    Quantity    Value\n");
    printf("-------------------------------------\n");

    for(i=0;i<100;i++){
        printf("%d          %.2lf      %d\n", barcode[i], price[i], quantity[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's the problem you're seeing with this code?

Comment: Why not `if (barcode[i]==0)` instead of `if (barcode[100]==0)` any way `barcode[100]` not exists, there are only `barcode[99]`

Comment: the program loops many times printing negative numbers

Comment: Hints: 1. Always check return value of `scanf` to detect parse errors (if you don't, you'll end up scratching your head for a long time for seemingly nonsensical bugs, when you accidentally give invalid input). 2. Indent your code (both for yourself, and for people who you ask for help here).

Answer (score 2):

The `break` in the first loop is with the wrong condition:

```
if (barcode[100]==0){

break;

}
```

it should be:

```
if (barcode[i]==0) break;
```

You should also stop the second loop when you attend the zero value in barcode.

```
for(i=0;i<100 && barcode[i] !=0;i++){
```

Comment: This helped a lot! By stopping the second loop when attending the zero value it has stopped the loop from printing negative numbers